# Show other form when click at the dynamic buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code when i choose date, creating buttons in the form. I want to show reservation from when button click, but i don't have specific button id what can i do?

```
public void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int cleft = 1;
    int btnclock = 9;
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        buttons.Add(newButton);
        newButton.Top = cleft * 20;
        newButton.Left = 100;
        cleft = cleft + 1;
        newButton.Text = btnclock.ToString();
        cleft = cleft + 1;
        this.Controls.Add(newButton);
        btnclock++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if I understand the question (in one point I will be able to actually ASK questions...)

You just want the buttonID? I see you do not have a click event defined, if you define a click event, the "sender" will be your button that you clicked.  You can get the ID text etc at that point.  I do hope this helps.
Add " newButton.Click += NewButton_Click;"
`

```
private void NewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button ButtonthatwasClicked = (Button)sender;
        Console.WriteLine(ButtonthatwasClicked.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(ButtonthatwasClicked.Text);
        }`
```

I leave the null checking etc to you.